# Responsive design with LaTeX

Tags: pdf, paper-size

Is there any concept similar to responsive design, as in [responsive web design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design), in TeX/LaTeX? That is, is it possible to include hints or directives that optimize layouts for different screens? PDFs are not suited to display well on small screens such as mobile phones and eBook readers. But with LaTeX is it as simple and changing the size of the document and exporting PDFs at different sizes for different devices? What if you want the final document to be resizable? Can you indicate at which point margins, font-sizes, and figures should change?

Comment: Text reflow in PDF is [very limited](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/reading-pdfs-reflow-accessibility-features.html#reflow_a_pdf). I think you're barking up the wrong tree, here.

Comment: You could definitely swapout different page sizes and create multiple PDF files. And use server side content negotiation to give the right size file for a given browser/OS.

Comment: @Jubobs it doesn't have to be a single PDF, or a PDF at all for that matter. I'm asking if there is support for device-independent export/display in LaTeX.

Comment: LaTeX is designed to print texts in paper of know size and printer options are in the PDF viewer (zoom, orientation, tc.). Said that, you have also some control of how show the PDF in the screen with the `hyperref` package (`pdfpagemode=FullScreen`, etc.) but not much more, I afraid.

Comment: Making a PDF for differents sizes (A4,A5, etc...) will produce disastrous results except for very simple layouts. Even with some conditionally changes (font size, margins, ...) and using  relative lengths instead of fixed lenghts  (i.e., `0.3\linewidth` instead of `5cm`) whenever is possible, too many things will break in a complex document.

Comment: Wrong media, try HTML.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197063/2891 where conversion to responsive html with `tex4ht` is showed

Comment: @michal.h21 does the HTML output match the typography of the PDF output? The reason I want to go with TeX is the beautiful typography. Otherwise I would use HTML and CSS.

Comment: @ReedG.Law formatting is preserved, typography not (it is really just html and css)

Comment: 5 years later, but you could also consider using pandoc. https://pandoc.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new output format under development called HINT that would support reflowing of type-set TeX output, see these articles for more information:

https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb39-3/tb123ruckert-hint.pdf

https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb40-2/tb125ruckert-hint.pdf

Of course, using a new file format comes with all sorts of problems, like viewer support on all sorts of devices, so this is probably not a usable solution for now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:pdf] so I don't think the HINT file format which is different from PDF qualifies as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I attempted to clarify my answer.  (Since the question says that "PDFs are not suited to display well ..." I assumed other file formats were ok to mention.)  Do let me know if the answer is not helpful / distracting and I'll happily remove it!

Comment: Thanks @Rudi this answer is helpful. I don't think PDF alone is sufficient.